# Set up a udp stream using c# with a vlc wrapper for the newest version of VLC

Tags: c#, wpf, udp, wrapper, vlc

I would like to set up a udp stream in a c# WPF application using a vlc wrapper. I am unsure how exactly to do this with the newest version of vlc, as most of the posts I have seen regarding wrappers are very outdated. Does anyone have any examples or advice on how to set up a wrapper in c# so that I can transmit and receive a udp stream without using the actual VLC GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/). It's an active project.